# How to get a HttpServletRequest attribute after resp.sendRedirect

Tags: servlets

Ok the problem is not very complex, but tricky to explain.
I'm working on a pure Jee webapp (no Spring).

I have a simple form filled by a user, from which i want two different results.
If there is a problem while i verify the data or save it to the database, it is sent back to the same form with some error getting displayed (That part is ok).
But if the form and the storage are ok, i want it to be sent to the dashboard of the user with a line displaying "recording complete".

I thought that i could do a

```
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/dashboard.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

but it can't be redirected to my dashboard via a jsp, because when i display the dashboard, an sql request is executed.

So i thought that i could do :

```
resp.sendRedirect("/dashboard.do");
```

to go once again through my servlet, in order to execute my request.

I use a boolean "result" in my model that i add to the request, but i cant get it back if i do a resp.sendRedirect

I tried to set a header in the response and to test it, but it didn't work out.

Here is an extract of my servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (path.equals("/saveSpot.do")){
        .......
        CheckForm form = new CheckForm();
        form.checkAndSave(req, "com.alain.dao.entities.Spot", spotDao);
        //here are the treatments on the form
        ....
        if (form.getResult()){
            resp.setHeader("result","true");
            resp.sendRedirect("/dashboard.do");
        } else {
            doGet(req,resp);
        }
    }
}

...
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if(path.equals("/ajoutSpot.do") || path.equals("/saveSpot.do")){
            // If the Post had a problem, it is sent back here
            ...
            some stuff are done
            ...
            // and the same jsp is called to display the errors
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/ajoutSpot.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }else if(path.equals("/dashboard.do")){
            //If the form is ok it is sent here
            //I try to test the header but it doesnt work
            if (resp.containsHeader("result")){
                req.setAttribute("result",true);
            }
            // I do my request
            SpotDaoImpl spotDao = new SpotDaoImpl();
            List<Spot> listSpots = spotDao.findAll();
            req.setAttribute("spots", listSpots);
            // And display the dashboard
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/dashboard.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }
```

I think my treatment of the result is clumsy, but i don't have a clue to do a better job.
Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the subject, i just passed a boolean parameter in the URL `resp.sendRedirect("/dashboard.do?resultat=true");`